# Output problems when printing an array and toString

Tags: java, arrays, loops, dialog

[image]I have three problems.

1) I have an array of ebooks that I am trying to print. The array is 25 elements long and I have placed 6 ebooks in it. When I print, it prints each ebook 25 times, rather than just once.

2) I have output at the end of my program that is printing a large decimal number before my desired print statement

3) How do I implement JOptionPane, or some other class, to print ALL output onto one dialog box?

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane; // dialog box

public class Ebook
{
    private String author = "";
    private String title = "";
    private double price = 0.0;
    private String isbn = "";


        public Ebook(String author, String title, double price, String isbn) // ebook constructor 
        {
            this.author = author;
            this.title = title;

            if (price > 0) // validate non-negative price
                this.price = price;

            else 
            {   
                this.price = 0.0; 
                    System.out.println("Invalid price");
            }

            if (isbn.length() == 10 || isbn.length() ==  13) // isbn length must be exactly 10 or 13
                this.isbn = isbn;

            else
                this.isbn = "None";
        }   

        public void setPrice(double price)
        {
            if (price < 0) // vallidate
            {
                System.out.println("Invalid price");
            }

            else
                this.price = price;
        }

        public double getPrice()
        {
            return price;
        }

        public void setAuthor(String theAuthor)
        {
            this.author = theAuthor;
        }

        public String getAuthor()
        {
            return author;
        }

        public void setIsbn(String isbn)
        {
            if (isbn.length() == 10 || isbn.length() ==  13) // validate
            {
                this.isbn = isbn;
            }
            else 
                isbn = "None";
        }

        public String getIsbn()
        {
            return isbn;
        }

        public void setTitle(String title)
        {
            this.title = title;
        }

        public String getTitle()
        {
            return title;
        }

        public String toString()
        {
            return String.format("Author: %s%nTitle: %s%nPrice: $%.1f%nISBN: %s%n",
                author,title,price,isbn);
        } 
} // This was made by ------

import javax.swing.JOptionPane; // dialog box

public class EbookLibrary
{
    private int count = 0;
    private double total_cost = 0.0;


    Ebook[] ebooks = new Ebook[25]; // array of ebook objects

    public EbookLibrary() // no argument constructor for ebooklibrary object in library test
    {

    }
    public int getCount() // total number of ebooks
    {
        return count;
    }
    public double getCost() // sum of all ebooks
    {
        return total_cost;
    }
    public String toString() // formatted string with the number and cost of all ebooks
    {
        return String.format("Ebook count: %d%nTotal Cost: $%.1f", count, total_cost);
    }
    public void addEbook(String author, String title, double price, String isbn) // adds ebooks to the array
    {
        Ebook anEbook = new Ebook(author,title,price,isbn); // not sure if this is a "constructor", but I think it is

        for (int counter = 0; counter < ebooks.length; counter++) // for the length of the array, add ebook
        {
            ebooks[counter] = anEbook; // for each counter, add the ebook 
                total_cost += price;
                    count++; // used to find the total number of ebooks
                        System.out.printf("%s%n", ebooks[counter]);

        }


    } 



} // This was made by -----

import javax.swing.JOptionPane; // dialog box

public class EbookLibraryTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        EbookLibrary aLibrary = new EbookLibrary(); // EbookLibrary object for calling addEbook

        //ebook objects, more can be added to test set, get methods
        aLibrary.addEbook("Blah", "What", 88.8, "1234567891");
        aLibrary.addEbook("Thing Do", "What What", 45.0, "1234567891111");
        aLibrary.addEbook("Stephen King","The Thing",1.1, "1234567891");
        aLibrary.addEbook("Robert","A Title", -1.0, "1234567891"); // test invalid price, should return 0.0 and "invalid price"
        aLibrary.addEbook("Tom","Bad Title", 33.1, "1234567891111");
        aLibrary.addEbook("Bob", "FML and Other Acronyms", 25.0, "1"); // test ISBN value, should return "None"




        System.out.printf("%d%f%s%n", aLibrary.getCount(), // call methods, print with toString
            aLibrary.getCost(), aLibrary.toString());

        System.out.println("Programmed by -----");

    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried to put this into the three separate class files that it is in, but I'm unsure how. There is an Ebook class, EbookLibrary class, EbookLibraryTest class.

Comment: What is printed out ? 'aLibrary.toString()' should print out only count, and total_cost.

Comment: I'd added a screenshot of my output, but I think it was deleted. It is up now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the problem is with your `addEbook` method in your `EbookLibrary` class.  Every time you add a new `Ebook`, you fill the entire `ebooks` array with it.  At each iteration, you're also incrementing the `total_cost` and the `count`.  I'm assuming you only want to add it one time to the array and verify that the array is not full before doing so.  Try this.

```
public void addEbook(String author, String title, double price, String isbn) // adds ebooks to the array
{
    if(count==ebooks.length-1) {
        return;
    }
    Ebook anEbook = new Ebook(author,title,price,isbn);

    ebooks[count] = anEbook;
    total_cost += price;
    System.out.printf("%s%n", anEbook);
    count++; // used to find the total number of ebooks
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. Could you explain why this code prints null rather than the book values?

Comment: @srmjr Yes that would be because I incremented the `count` before printing.  That was another mistake I forgot to fix.  I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks. Very helpful. I honestly didn't even consider the order of the increment and its effect on the printing. Still learning. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The decimal number is due to this line:
    System.out.printf("%d%f%s%n", aLibrary.getCount(), aLibrary.getCost(), aLibrary.toString());

The `%d` displays an integer, but the `%f` displays a float; remove it and this part will work.

Your `addEbook` function is also wrong; it fills the entire array with a single Ebook, and displays it each time (which leads to it being displayed 25 times).

Comment: Ah, I'm not sure why I thought I needed to call everything in one print statement. I called getCount and getCost and then called toString separately. It worked. Thank you. As for the second part, I have fixed the issue with it printing over and over, but now it is printing "null" for the book values.                                                                                   `Ebook anEbook = new Ebook(author,title,price,isbn);
  
  ebooks[count] = anEbook;
  total_cost += price;
  count++;
  System.out.printf("%s%n", ebooks[count]);`

Comment: Could you provide an updated version of your code? I suggest using [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) to link it (free and no registration needed).

Comment: `Ebook anEbook = new Ebook("blah","blah",1.0,"123");
  
  ebooks[count] = anEbook;
  total_cost += price;
  count++;
  System.out.printf("%s%n", ebooks[count]);`                                              So that prints null 6 times and then the correct count and price. Sorry about code format. I tried using pastebin earlier and was told not to.

Comment: The `null` comes from your `printf`. You are incrementing `count`, just before, so `ebooks[count]` no longer points to an existing `Ebook`. That is why `null` is displayed.